# What's the proper way to update the Lexical state

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

we are migrating from draft-js to Lexical,
I need to change fractions to single-character fractions(1/4 ==>  ¼) and I use onChange for this purpose

```
  function onChange(editorState: EditorState, editor: LexicalEditor) {
      const stringifiedEditorState = JSON.stringify(
        editor.getEditorState().toJSON(),
      );
      const parsedEditorState = editor.parseEditorState(stringifiedEditorState);
    
      const editorStateTextString = parsedEditorState.read(() => $getRoot().getTextContent())
      const formattedText = editorStateTextString.replace(/[1-9][0-9]*\/[1-9][0-9]*/i, fraction => {
        const [top, bottom] = fraction.split('/');
        return fractionToCharacter({
          top: +top,
          bottom: +bottom,
        });
      });
      const updatedEditorState = editor.parseEditorState(formattedText);
      editor.setEditorState(updatedEditorState);
  }

<OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
```

but the UI is not updated, do you have any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: can you please share your full code so I can reproduce? Thanks

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors?